# Array manipulation error with regex - Kata 6 Codewar

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, replace

In theory it should transform a given array to camel case. I don't understand what is wrong

```
function toCamelCase(str){
 if(str.length === 0) return ""
 let array = str.split(/([_-])/);
 array.forEach(word =>{
   word == "-" ? word.replace("") : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
 })
  
 return array
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should change as @MonkeyZeus Stated and also change  `str.split(/([_-])/);` to  `str.split(/[_-]/);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method doesn't modify the `word` variable, it instead returns a new modified string. So your code is producing new values within the loop but doesn't do anything with those values. Moreover, `word` here is a value and not a reference to your array values, so you can't modify them directly from within your `forEach()` loop and expect it to modify the string values from your array. You instead need to create a new array, with each element transformed, which can be done by using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and returning the new value:

```js
function toCamelCase(str) {
  const array = str.split(/[_-]/);
  return array.map((word, i) => {
    return i === 0 ? word : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
  }).join("");
}

console.log(toCamelCase("this-is-some-text"));
```

Note that you can remove the capturing group from your `.split()` to remove the `_` and `-` chars from your `array` so that you don't need to remove them when you map.

Note that for something like this, if you're already using regular expressions in your `.split()`, you might consider using `.replace()` with a [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters), for example, something like:

```js
function toCamelCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/-\w/g, ([,m]) => m.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(toCamelCase("this-is-some-text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`word == "-" ? word.replace("") : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()` is just a ternary statement floating in space. This code isn't altering any variables. It's equivalent to:

```
if(word == "-"){
    word.replace("")
}
else{
    word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()
}
```

Really, you don't need to mess with arrays if you make use of `.replace()`'s callback function.

```js
function toCamelCase(str) {
    // Match underscore or dash followed by a letter, case-insensitively
    // Store the letter in a capture group; $1 in this case
    return str.replace( /[_-]([a-z])/gi, function( matches ) {
        // Uppercase the letter
        return matches[ 1 ].toUpperCase()
    } );
}

console.log( toCamelCase( 'to-be_Camel_cased' ) );
```

Comment: Why is it floating? How could I make that section work?

Comment: @Lu-deng It's "floating" because it's not doing anything with the execution result. You're just executing a logic operator in mid-air and not assigning the result nor returning it.